# Circuit without grounding

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, potential, voltage

I'm learning about the notation of grounding.

In this post of Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_ground, it is said that

> Conductors are also described as having a floating voltage if they are not connected electrically to another non-floating (grounded) conductor. Without such a connection, voltages and current flows are induced by electromagnetic fields or charge accumulation within the conductor rather than being due to the usual external potential difference of a power source.

How can it be possible that if without grounding, the voltage and current are induced by the charge accumulation within the conductor and **NOT** the potential difference of a power source?
If it is the case, then what is the role of a power source here?

Could you please explain me why the quotation above is correct?

Comment: You should read [the talk page for that article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Floating_ground) before you put too much faith in it.

Answer (score 0):

An ungrounded system immersed in an oscillating electromagnetic field can pick up energy from the field. Or, it can have an *internal* energy source, a battery, for example.

Note that ordinary electric appliances that plug into the wall generally need not be grounded to operate. The return current for the "hot" wire flows back through "neutral" to the utility transformer without flowing through ground. Neutral is normally grounded for safety, to avoid the possibility that it could float to a dangerously high potential, but that's not necessary to deliver energy.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but I don't understand why do you mean "a battery" an internal source ? If it is the case, what is an example of external power source according to you ? Thanks.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge Is your cell phone grounded?

Comment: Hello, of course not, but I still can't see your point with that question... Sorry :(

Comment: Can you please be more specific ? Thanks!!!

Comment: “Note that ordinary electric appliances that plug into the wall generally need not be grounded to operate”.  What electrical appliances need to be grounded in order to operate?

Comment: @BobD Some years ago I flew to Japan. For my laptop, I packed my Japanese power cord: it has no "U" ground, just a lug you can connect to a ground screw. Still, it works fine on ordinary North American power without a ground connection. When I boarded the the plane, I found innovation: an AC outlet under my seat. Great, don't have to ration battery power on the 12 hour flight. But during the flight, I discovered the track pad didn't work when I plugged the AC adapter in. Guessing that this was a common mode noise problem, the next trip I packed a US cord, too, and then the track pad worked.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Are you saying you’re laptop won’t work if it is plugged into a non grounded (two wire) outlet?

Comment: @BobD Effectively, yes. Three wire outlet, but two wire cord.

Comment: I presently don’t have a laptop now but when I did I don’t recall the adapter having a grounding pin

Comment: @BobD Depends on the laptop. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17575/how-to-properly-ground-a-macbook-pro

Comment: It sounds to me like the case needs to be grounded only so as not to experience annoying (but not necessarily hazardous) leakage current from case due to an EMI filter. That’s not the same thing as saying grounding is necessary for the laptop to perform its intended function. I’ve never heard of grounding, which is intended to prevent electric shock in the event of an internal fault to a conductive housing, being needed to perform intended operation.

Comment: Of course EMI filtering reduces the risk of conductive EMI from interfering with operation

Comment: @BobD You have heard of it, I told you! Why is it so surprising that current through the EMI filter could cause track pad trouble?